# Which is efficient - multiple rows or single text field in database?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store instantaneous GPS location in database. Currently I'm storing location in rows and for future trip viewing I fetch location from those rows.

Now I'm thinking of taking all the locations once the trip is over and storing it into a text field as json data for later mapping.

Is that an efficient method? There would be thousands of rows if done in a-row-for-every-location-information.

Comment: If you design the database right, leaving the rows (no matter how many) will always be the better data source than storing something as text somewhere. You lose all the database features (filtering, sorting, updating, etc.) if you modify the data the way you describe. Storing lots of data is a database's job. It may not be convenient for you to look at, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't require future modification. It's just for viewing the GPS path.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Let the database do its job :-)